# Issue with "Running a FLOW automatically on a Schedule"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerapps, power-automate

I have a flow inside my powerbi report that is triggered on demand. but I need to run it automatically every 2 weeks. I have found another flow "schedule" but I can't connect that to my existing flow.

The issue is that the ON POWER BI BUTTON CLICKED step is a trigger and can't be used after the schedule step because it's a trigger itself:

```
    {
    "kind": "apiconnection",
    "splitOn": "@triggerBody()['rows']",
    "inputs": {
        "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {},
            "required": []
        },
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['shared_powerbi']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "operationId": "PowerBiButtonClicked",
        "parameters": {
            "inputsPowerBiData": "{}",
            "pbi_source": "powerAutomate"
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be great. thanks,

Comment: Cant you just get the data from the actual source? Where is that Power BI data located? If you schedule it and want a static filter, you should be able to do it from the data.

Comment: thanks for your reply but no that's not the case. Here I have a power automate visual inside my powerbi report. that flow needs to be triggered on demand (on click) but I am looking for a way to automatically trigger that flow on a schedule. I have found there is a premium flow (paid) that might be able to do it but wanted to know if there is any other way inside powerbi.

Comment: Why cant you get it from the actual source? What you just reiterated was that you are just trying to create a Scheduled Flow based on your Data inside of Power BI. I understand you can click a button to trigger a flow in Power BI. But if you need it scheduled, you would just get it from the data source.

Comment: Can you explain to me why you think you couldn’t get it form the data source?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using [Trigger a cloud flow from any message in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-flow-powerbi-report) and yes there is one premium flow for what you are trying to achieve.

As a workaround:

Option 1:

> You could try editing your flow as [Run flows on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks) and use [when a data driven alert is triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerbi/#when-a-data-driven-alert-is-triggered)

[image]

Option 2:

> Use On Power BI button clicked for start and then [use wait conditions to delay flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/dataverse/wait-conditions)

[image]

[Known limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-flow-powerbi-report#known-limitations)

1. The user running the flow within the Power BI report needs to have permissions to run the flow. Grant these permissions through direct sharing by the user or by sharing to an Azure Active Directory group.
2. The PowerBI visual only functions with flows in a tenant's default environment. Any flow created with the visual is created in the users default environment.
3. Additional manual inputs to the button are not supported at this time.
4. The visual is not supported for PaaS embedded scenarios nor in Sovereign Cloud scenarios.
5. Create flows that you will use with the Power BI button trigger directly within the Power BI report. Do not go directly to Power automate to create these flows as the trigger will not have access to the data fields necessary for creating the flow.
6. Power BI data will be sent to and processed in a geography where the flow is deployed